# Spring Boot + Jetty + SSL Port

Tags: embedded-jetty, spring-boot

How can I configure Spring Boot to run Jetty with HTTPS port at 443. The configuration should also take care of generating the key.

In short, the equivalent configuration of following maven plugins,:-

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>keytool-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <id>clean</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>clean</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <id>genkey</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>generateKeyPair</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <keystore>${project.build.directory}/jetty-ssl.keystore</keystore>
    <dname>cn=my.hostname.tld</dname>
    <!-- put your CN here -->
    <keypass>jetty6</keypass>
    <storepass>jetty6</storepass>
    <alias>jetty6</alias>
    <keyalg>RSA</keyalg>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and:-

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.26</version>
  <configuration>
    <jvmArgs>-Xmx2048m -Xms1536m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</jvmArgs>
    <!-- http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin -->
    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
    <connectors>
      <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        <port>9999</port>
        <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
      </connector>
      <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector">
        <port>9993</port>
        <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
        <keystore>${project.build.directory}/jetty-ssl.keystore</keystore>
        <password>jetty6</password>
        <keyPassword>jetty6</keyPassword>
      </connector>
    </connectors>
    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of Spring Boot 1.1.7 you can configure both Jetty and Tomcat to use SSL via three properties in your properties file as shown in the [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-configure-ssl)

Configuring SSL via these properties will enable HTTPS and disable HTTP because using only the properties files does not allow for both. If you want to serve both simultaneously [Spring recommends](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2167) you configure HTTPS (SSL) via the properties and configure HTTP programmatically.

Answer (score 6):

I found this solution. It Works fine for me. 
This method can support both HTTP and HTTPS.

```java
@Component
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer servletContainerCustomizer() {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
            if (container instanceof JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
                customizeJetty((JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container);
            }
        }

        private void customizeJetty(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory container) {

    container.addServerCustomizers(new JettyServerCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(Server server) {

            // HTTP
            ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
            connector.setPort(requestHttpPort());

            // HTTPS
            SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
            sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath("mykeystore.jks");
            sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("1234");

            HttpConfiguration https = new HttpConfiguration();
            https.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

            ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(
                    server,
                    new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.asString()),
                    new HttpConnectionFactory(https));
            sslConnector.setPort(requestHttpsPort());

            server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { connector, sslConnector });

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To add the SSL connector to Jetty you need to declare an `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` bean in your application's configuration. That will ultimately give you access to a Jetty `Server` instance where you can use Jetty's API to make your desired configuration changes. Something similar to this:

```java
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer servletContainerCustomizer() {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
            if (container instanceof JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
                customizeJetty((JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container);
            }
        }

        private void customizeJetty(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory) {
            factory.addServerCustomizers(new JettyServerCustomizer() {

                @Override
                public void customize(Server server) {
                    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
                    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("jetty6");
                    try {
                        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(ResourceUtils.getFile(
                                "classpath:jetty-ssl.keystore").getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not load keystore", ex);
                    }
                    SslSocketConnector sslConnector = new SslSocketConnector(
                            sslContextFactory);
                    sslConnector.setPort(9993);
                    sslConnector.setMaxIdleTime(60000);
                    server.addConnector(sslConnector);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

There's no support in Spring Boot for automatically generating a keystore. I'd continue to use the keytool Maven plugin for that.

Comment: "SslSocketConnector cannot be resolved to a type". Where can I find this class ?

Comment: What version of Jetty are you using ?

Comment: That was with 8.1.14, which is the version that Boot 1.0.2 provides by default if you're using its dependency management.

Comment: it did not work me. logs show that Jetty starterd on port: 9993 ( without @0.0.0.0) and I can not access to home page in browser https://127.0.0.1:9993

Answer (score 2):

For spring boot newer version (2.1.x). Try below code, basically EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer and ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer have been replaced as below:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpVersion;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServerCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils;

@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<JettyServletWebServerFactory> webServerFactoryCustomizer() {

        return new WebServerFactoryCustomizer<JettyServletWebServerFactory>() {

            @Override
            public void customize(JettyServletWebServerFactory factory) {

                factory.addServerCustomizers(new JettyServerCustomizer() {

                    @Override
                    public void customize(Server server) {

                        ServerConnector httpConnector = new ServerConnector(server);
                        httpConnector.setPort(8080);

                        SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
                        try {
                            sslContextFactory
                                    .setKeyStorePath(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:keystore.jks").getAbsolutePath());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }

                        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("password");

                        HttpConfiguration httpsConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
                        httpsConfiguration.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

                        ServerConnector httpsConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
                                new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.asString()),
                                new HttpConnectionFactory(httpsConfiguration));
                        httpsConnector.setPort(8090);

                        server.setConnectors(new Connector[] {httpConnector, httpsConnector});
                    }
                });

            }
        };
    }
}
```